# Python ElementTree support for parsing unknown XML entities?

Tags: python, xml, openstreetmap

I have a set of super simple XML files to parse... but... they use custom defined entities.  I don't need to map these to characters, but I do wish to parse and act on each one.  For example:

```
<Style name="admin-5678">
    <Rule>
      <Filter>[admin_level]='5'</Filter>
      &maxscale_zoom11;
    </Rule>
</Style>
```

There is a tantalizing hint at http://effbot.org/elementtree/elementtree-xmlparser.htm that XMLParser has limited entity support, but I can't find the methods mentioned, everything gives errors:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    ##
    ## Where's the entity support as documented at:
    ## http://effbot.org/elementtree/elementtree-xmlparser.htm
    ## In Python 2.7.1+ ?
    ##
    from pprint     import pprint
    from xml.etree  import ElementTree
    from cStringIO  import StringIO

    parser = ElementTree.ElementTree()
   #parser.entity["maxscale_zoom11"] = unichr(160)
    testf = StringIO('<foo>&maxscale_zoom11;</foo>')
    tree = parser.parse(testf)
   #tree = parser.parse(testf,"XMLParser")
    for node in tree.iter('foo'):
        print node.text
```

Which depending on how you adjust the comments gives:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity: line 1, column 5
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'entity'
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'feed'
```

For those curious the XML is from the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)'s mapnik project.

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524299/entity-references-and-lxml

Comment: Not related, because in that case the entity is actually defined.  Remove the entity definition and you're back to my question.

Comment: fyi - someone may want to fix the /usr/bin/python to /usr/bin/env python as the shebang line is wrong for most systems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug in ElementTree or what, but you need to call UseForeignDTD(True) on the expat parser to behave the way it did in the past.

It's a bit hacky, but you can do this by creating your own instance of ElementTree.Parser, calling the method on it's instance of xml.parsers.expat, and then passing it to ElementTree.parse():

```
from xml.etree  import ElementTree
from cStringIO  import StringIO


testf = StringIO('<foo>&moo_1;</foo>')

parser = ElementTree.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity['moo_1'] = 'MOOOOO'

etree = ElementTree.ElementTree()

tree = etree.parse(testf, parser=parser)

for node in tree.iter('foo'):
    print node.text
```

This outputs "MOOOOO"

Or using a mapping interface:

```
from xml.etree  import ElementTree
from cStringIO  import StringIO

class AllEntities:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        #key is your entity, you can do whatever you want with it here
        return key

testf = StringIO('<foo>&moo_1;</foo>')

parser = ElementTree.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity = AllEntities()

etree = ElementTree.ElementTree()

tree = etree.parse(testf, parser=parser)

for node in tree.iter('foo'):
    print node.text
```

This outputs "moo_1"

A more complex fix would be to subclass ElementTree.XMLParser and fix it there.

Comment: A bit icky as as you say, but thanks.  Is there any way to avoid having to predefine the entities (e.g. &moo_2).

Comment: @Bryce: being predefined is the point of entities, no? Nevertheless: you could set `parser.entity` to your own dictionary-like object. As a simple example, you could do `parser.entity = collections.defaultdict(str)` to have all undefined entities replaced by an empty string.

Comment: To follow up @Steven's comment, you could also implement a mapping interface and do whatever you want with the keys.  I edited my answer to show a simple example of that.

Comment: The code works with Python 2.7 (in earlier versions `parse()` does not accept a `parser` keyword argument).

Comment: Yes, 2.7+; I was answering the OP's question that was hidden in the comments of his sample code: ## Where's the entity support as documented at http://effbot.org/elementtree/elementtree-xmlparser.htm In Python 2.7.1+?.

Comment: This won't work in Python 3 with cpython, where the C versions (formerly `cElementTree` are being used instead).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible at all in Python 3 currently. Looking at the the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xmlparser-objects) I see the following method signature **xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser(html=0, target=None, encoding=None)**  but the docs say _Element structure builder for XML source data, based on the expat parser. html are predefined HTML entities. This flag is not supported by the current implementation._   It looks like element tree is getting more strict and if your entities aren't defined, then it's not valid and won't be parsed.

Comment: I had this working in 2.7 in an overridden ElementTree XMLParser, but I can no longer extend that in 3.5 as you point out, because inheriting from the cElementTree parser is not possible. Not sure if I should be pushing my content through a custom codec before parsing, or what. Is there a standard answer for python 3?

Answer (score 16):

As @cnelson already pointed out in a comment, the chosen solution here won't work in Python 3.

I finally got it working. Quoted from this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591478/how-to-parse-html-with-entities-such-as-nbsp-using-builtin-library-elementtree).

Inspired by [this post](http://forums.devshed.com/xml-programming-19/xml-parsing-error-undefined-entity-564981.html), we can just prepend some XML definition to the incoming raw HTML content, and then ElementTree would work out of box.

This works for both Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = '''<html>
    <div>Some reasonably well-formed HTML content.</div>
    <form action="login">
    <input name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <input name="username"/><input name="password"/>

    <div>It is not unusual to see &nbsp; in an HTML page.</div>

    </form></html>'''

magic = '''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [
            <!ENTITY nbsp ' '>
            ]>'''  # You can define more entities here, if needed

et = ET.fromstring(magic + html)
```

Comment: This only applies to HTML documents though, right? The notion of 'DOCTYPE' processing instructions does not apply to "simple XML files " as the OP is apparently dealing with.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, Sorry, admittedly I did not test it on XML docs. That answer was quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591478/how-to-parse-html-with-entities-such-as-nbsp-using-builtin-library-elementtree), and was hoping it would be helpful. That original Q&A link contains another answer that may or may not help in your situation.