# How to resolve external entities with xml.etree like lxml.etree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, xml-entities

I have a script that parses XML using `lxml.etree`:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(load_dtd=True, resolve_entities=True)
tree = etree.parse('main.xml', parser=parser)
```

I need `load_dtd=True` and `resolve_entities=True` be have `&emptyEntry;` from `globals.xml` resolved:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE map SYSTEM "globals.xml" [
    <!ENTITY dirData "${DATADIR}"> 
]>
<map 
    xmlns:map="http://my.dummy.org/map"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsschemaLocation="http://my.dummy.org/map main.xsd"
>

  &emptyEntry; <!-- from globals.xml -->

  <entry><key>KEY</key><value>VALUE</value></entry>
  <entry><key>KEY</key><value>VALUE</value></entry>
</map>
```

with `globals.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY emptyEntry "<entry></entry>">
```

Now I would like to move from non-standard `lxml` to standard `xml.etree`. But this fails with my file because the `load_dtd=True` and `resolve_entities=True` is not supported by `xml.etree`.

**Is there an `xml.etree`-way to have these entities resolved?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lxml is a right tool for the job.

But, if you want to use stdlib, then be prepared for difficulties and take a look at XMLParser's UseForeignDTD method. Here's a good (but hacky) example: [Python ElementTree support for parsing unknown XML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237466/python-elementtree-support-for-parsing-unknown-xml-entities)

Answer (score 1):

My trick is to use the external program xmllint

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['xmllint','--noent',fname],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
tree = ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(output))
```