# ElementTree's iterparse() XML parsing error

Tags: python, xml

I need to parse a 1.2GB XML file that has an encoding of "ISO-8859-1", and after reading a few articles on the NET, it seems that Python's ElementTree's iterparse() is preferred as to SAX parsing.

I've written a extremely short piece of code just to test it out, but it's prompting out an error that I've no idea how to solve.

My Code (Python 2.7):

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

for (event, node) in iterparse('dblp.xml', events=['start']):
    print node.tag
    node.clear()
```

**Edit:** Ahh, as the file was really big and laggy, I typed out the XML line, and made a mistake. It's "& uuml;" without the space. I apologize for this.

This code works fine until it hits a line in the XML file that looks like this:

```
<Journal>Technical Report 248, ETH Z&uuml;rich, Dept of Computer Science</Journal>
```

which I guess means Zurich, but the parser does not seem to know this.

Running the code above gave me an error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &uuml;
```

Is there anyway I could solve this issue? I've googled quite a few solutions, but none seem to deal with this problem directly.

Comment: Ok, you've got an inconsistancy that needs resolving. In the XML you have `&umml` and in the error you have `&uuml`. If they are both `&umml` is because the XML is invalid and needs correcting. If they are both `&uuml` that *is* a defined entity so should work. If they are actually different you'll need to give some more info on the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse, XMLParser
import htmlentitydefs

class CustomEntity:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'umml':
            key = 'uuml' # Fix invalid entity
        return unichr(htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint[key])

parser = XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity = CustomEntity()

for (event, node) in iterparse('dblp.xml', events=['start'], parser=parser):
    print node.tag
    node.clear()
```

OR

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse, XMLParser
import htmlentitydefs

parser = XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity = {'umml': unichr(htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint['uuml'])}

for (event, node) in iterparse('dblp.xml', events=['start'], parser=parser):
    print node.tag
    node.clear()
```

Related question: [Python ElementTree support for parsing unknown XML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237466/python-elementtree-support-for-parsing-unknown-xml-entities)

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer; the OP states that it's `uuml`, not `umml`...

Comment: I've seen it; I just wonder why this is the accepted answer, given that it doesn't really answer the question in its current form.