# Python ElementTree ParseError from iterparse when reaching escape character (XML)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

This question appears related to [this one from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840959/elementtrees-iterparse-xml-parsing-error), but it didn't help me.

I'm about to parse a large (2GB) XML file, and plan to do it with Python 3.5.2 and ElementTree. I'm new to Python, but it works well until reaching any escape character, such as:

```
<author>Sanjeev Sax&ouml;na</author>
```

returning:

```
test.xml
  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: undefined entity &ouml;: line 5, column 19enter code here
```

My code looks something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
for event, elem in etree.iterparse('test_esc.xml'):
  # do something with the node
```

What's the best way to deal with this? Parsing the unescaped 'ö' actually works fine:

```
<author>Sanjeev Saxöna</author>
```

Is there an easy way to programmatically unescape the whole XML file?

Comment: there an answer here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744945/parse-xml-with-xhtml-entities>

Comment: Thanks! That answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the answer linked by Soulaimane Sahmi, I added an inline DTD to the XML file. It is maybe not the best solution out there, but it works for now.