# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError -- exception handling not catching errors

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse [an xml document](https://github.com/DLibatique/texts/blob/master/xml_tests/cic.fam_lat.xml) that has a number of undefined entities that cause a ParseError when I try to run my code, which is as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('cic.fam_lat.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

while True:
    try:
        for name in root.iter('name'):
            print(root.tag, name.text)
    except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
        pass

for name in root.iter('name'):
    print(name.text)
```

An example of said error is as follows, and there are a number of undefined entities that will all throw the same error:
[image: error description]

I just want to ignore them rather than go in and edit out each one. How should I edit my exception handling to catch these error instances? (i.e., what am I doing wrong?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some workarounds, like defining custom entities, suggested at:

- [Python ElementTree support for parsing unknown XML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237466/python-elementtree-support-for-parsing-unknown-xml-entities)

But, if you are able to switch to `lxml`, its [`XMLParser()`](http://lxml.de/api/index.html) can work in the *"recover" mode* that would "ignore" the undefined entities:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = ET.parse('cic.fam_lat.xml', parser=parser)

for name in root.iter('name'):
    print(root.tag, name.text)
```

(worked for me - got the tag names and texts printed)

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Yeah, lxml seems to be the way to go -- recover mode worked perfectly. Now just to figure out how to get to a certain parent tag from each instance of <name>...

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Why is the `ParseError` not caught?

Comment: @LondonRob: The exception is thrown already at `tree = ET.parse('cic.fam_lat.xml')`. The document is ill-formed because of the undefined entity and ElementTree refuses to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the exception simply by referencing the `ParseError` like this:

```
try:
    # Something neat

except ET.ParseError:
    # Exception catch
```

This is on Python 3.7.10, Windows 10.