# how to read a xml file python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have this huge xml file around 15000 lines.
So when I try to read the content I get this error called

***ParseError: undefined entity &copy ;: line 108, column 14***

So the presence of **&copy ;** inside the xml is causing me this error
Even If I remove that there are other elements such as **&ndash ;** which is causing this error

This is the code I tried as per documentation

**CODE:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Please help me out guys incase if you know

Comment: Guys please do answer. I still havent found the solution

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917835/407651